# Cordova FileTransfer abort error

Tags: file, cordova, transfer, abort

I am using cordova to develop my app. When i using file transfer plugin, the following error occurred.

```
{"target":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/com.ibm.systems.supportassistant\/001\/1.1.0.12.zip","http_status":200,"code":3,"source":"http:\/\/messagefindertest.mybluemix.net\/001\/1.1.0.12.zip","exception":"length=4096; regionStart=0; regionLength=-2467"}

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4096; regionStart=0; regionLength=-2467
```

[Error message in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1U4M.png)

Any help in resolving the issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. It is a bug of the file transfer plugin. This bug have been fixed by the new version on CB-8431 Catch workaround for fatal exception.